# JavaScript onchange, onblur, and focus weirdness in Firefox

Tags: javascript, firefox, focus, onchange, onblur

On my form I have a discount field that accepts a dollar amount to be taken off of the total bill (HTML generated in PHP):

```
echo "<input id=\"discount\" class=\"text\" type=\"text\" name=\"discount\" onkeypress=\"return currency(this, event)\" onchange=\"currency_format(this)\" onfocus=\"on_focus(this)\" onblur=\"on_blur(this); calculate_bill()\"/><br/><br/>\n";
```

The JavaScript function `calculate_bill` calculates the bill and takes off the discount amount as long as the discount amount is less than the total bill:

```
    if(discount != ''){

        if(discount - 0.01 > total_bill){
            window.alert('Discount Cannot Be Greater Than Total Bill');
            document.form.discount.focus();
        }

        else{
            total_bill -= discount;
        }

    }
```

The problem is that even that when the discount is more than the total bill focus is not being returned to the discount field.  I have tried calling the `calculate_bill` function with `onchange` but neither IE or Firefox will return focus to the discount field when I do it like that.  When I call `calculate_bill` with `onblur` it works in IE, but still does not work in Firefox.  I have attempted to use a confirmation box instead of an alert box as well, but that didn't work either (plus I don't want two buttons, I only an "OK" button).

**How can I ensure focus is returned to the discount field after a user has left that field by clicking on another field or tabbing IF the discount amount is larger than the total bill?**

Comment: Just a hint: You would not need to escape the double quotes if you wrap the string in single quotes or don't use echo at all.

Comment: @Felix Kling I use single quotes for JavaScript and double quotes for PHP, seems less confusing that way. I just tried NOT using echo like you said, but that doesn't work. I use PHP to generate the HTML via `echo` so I can have the HTML say different things depending on variables passed in the URL. If you think I am confused please elaborate.

Comment: @typoknig: It is not easy to write code in the comments, I just meant, instead of writing e.g. `<?php echo "<div id=\"$id\">$text</div>"; ?>`, you can write `<div id="<?php echo $id; ?>"><?php echo $text; ?></div>` which is better style.

Comment: @Felix Kling I see what you mean, I actually do that where I can, but in this particular instance the HTML tags in question are there if a certain URL variable has been passed, and are not there if it has not been passed.

Comment: @typoknig: I see. But you can still do it this way (sorry for being annoying on that), e.g.: `<?php if(isset($_GET['key'])): ?> <!-- HTML here --> <?php endif; ?>`. It's the *alternative syntax for control structures* and is pretty handy in combination with HTML: http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php (just want to give some tips ;))

Comment: @Felix Kling I appreciate the tips! In fact I wish you would have given me this tip a year ago :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to try the technique described here: [Javascript / Firefox / onBlur](http://mrmx.blogspot.com/2005/12/javascript-firefox-onblur-focus.html.)

I haven't tried it myself, but essentially it suggests to replace `document.form.discount.focus()` with

```
setTimeout(function() {document.form.discount.focus();}, 1);
```

I suspect the underlying problem is that when you hit tab (for example), the browser goes through a few steps: call the code assosiated with the current control (onchange, onblur), then set the focus to the new control. So if you change focus in the first step, then the focus will still get reset immediately in the next step. Hence the timer-based workaround.

Answer (score -1):

You better convert the discount to a number when you are using it in number comparisions.
Change your script to:

```
if(discount != ''){
        discount = parseFloat(discount);
        if(discount - 0.01 > total_bill){
            window.alert('Discount Cannot Be Greater Than Total Bill');
            document.form.discount.focus();
        }

        else{
            total_bill -= discount;
        }

    }
```

Comment: The subtraction subexpression will convert it to a number.

Comment: what @Pointy said, plus I have already formatted it with the functions called by `onkeypress` and `onchange`.